# Choosing "Conjugating element" from a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H\leq G$ and $N\unlhd G$ such that $G=HN$ and $H\cap N= (1)$.

My question is

> Prove that if two elements of $H$ are conjugate in $G$, then they are conjugate in $H$.

What i have done so far is :

Suppose $a,b\in H$ are conjugate, i.e., we have $g\in G$ such that $a=gbg^{-1}$.

$g\in G$ so, we have $g=mn$ for $m\in H$ and $n\in N$

As $a\in H$ and $a=gbg^{-1}$ we see that $gbg^{-1}\in H$

please provide some hint for this.

Thank You.
$mnbn^{-1}m^{-1}\in H$ this imply $nbn^{-1}\in H$ as $m\in H$

with $nbn^{-1}\in H$ some how i want to conclude $n=e$

I have not yet used the condition that $N\unlhd G$

I thought of using that for $nbn^{-1}$ but then i realized $n\in N$ not $b$. :(

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that if $a, b\in H$ are conjugate in $G$ then there exists some $n\in N$ such that $a_0=nbn^{-1}$ where $a$ and $a_0$ are conjugate in $H$.

**Hint:** This, combined with the normality of $N$, implies there exists some $n_0\in N$ such that $a_0=bn_0n^{-1}$. Then use that fact that $H\cap N=1$ to conclude that $a_0=b$ (and $n_0=n$).

Comment: i feel that i understand this But i am getting confused.

Comment: @Praphulla About which bit?

Comment: I understand that "You have shown that if $a,b\in H$ are conjugate in $G$ then there exists some $n\in N$ such that $a_0=nbn^{−1}$ where $a$ and $a_0$ are conjugate in $H$."

Comment: I am confused about the Hint.

Comment: Since $n \in N$, $b^{-1}nb \in N$, and we'll call it $n_0$. $nb = bb^{-1}nb = b n_0$.

Comment: @Praphulla The the first sentence, use the normality of $N$ (as Henry Swanson has just demonstrated, 16 seconds before I posted this comment!).

Comment: ok, Ok. It is now clear :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be really nice if we had a homomorphism $\phi : G \to H$ that fixes $H$. Then, we could easily find a conjugating element in $H$:
$$a = gbg^{-1} \implies \phi(a) = \phi(g) \phi(b) \phi(g)^{-1} \implies a = \phi(g) \ b \ \phi(g)^{-1}$$

Since $G = HN$, each element can be written as $hn$, where $h \in H$ and $n \in N$. We define $\phi(hn)$ to be $h$. But we have to show that $\phi$ is well-defined. It turns out that the $h$-$n$ decomposition is unique. Say $h_1 n_1 = h_2 n_2$. Then $h_2^{-1} h_1 = n_2 n_1^{-1}$. The left side must be in $H$, and the right side in $N$. But these subgroups intersect trivially! So both sides must equal the identity. Therefore, $h_1 = h_2$ and $n_1 = n_2$.

Lastly, we make sure it's a homomorphism:
$$ \phi(h_1 n_1) \phi(h_2 n_2) = h_1 h_2 $$
$$ \phi(h_1 n_1 \cdot h_2 n_2) = \phi(h_1 h_2 \cdot h_2^{-1} n_1 h_2 \cdot n_2) = \phi(h_1 h_2 n_1' n_2) = h_1 h_2 $$